# Sorting list array from firebase database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

again I need a bit of help from you people:-)!

I want to sort data in *ngFor by value "finished"
[image]

I get my data with :

```
 this.db.list(`/avatars/`).valueChanges().subscribe(d => {
      this.avatarhall = d;
```

and show it in html like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let to of avatarhall; let i = index">
      <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail item-start>
              <img src="../assets/ghosts/{{to.avatar}}">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <h1> {{to.monstername}}</h1>
            <p>Finished Tasks:{{to.finished}}</p>
            <ion-icon name="star" item-end>{{i +1}}</ion-icon>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

  </div>
```

My pipe is created but I don't know how to sort it by the value of finished:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderbytask',
})
export class OrderbytaskPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], args:string):any[] {

    return value.sort();
  }
}
```

In real, this is a part of app where you can check your position on the ladder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript built in sort function.

```
 this.db.list(`/avatars/`).valueChanges().subscribe(d => {
      this.avatarhall = d.sort((a,b) => a.finished - b.finished);
```

You can find documentation of sort at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: I am getting back `property 'finished' does not exists on type '{}'`.

Comment: try  (a as any).finished - (b as any).finished

Answer (score 1):

I made it by doing :

```
this.db.list(`/avatars/`).valueChanges().subscribe(d => {

  this.avatarhall = d.sort((a,b) => (a as any).finished - (b as any).finished).reverse();

    });
```

hope someone will find this to be useful. Also, thanks @alt255 for link and starting idea that helped me to figure it out!

Comment: I took out time to help you with your problem and you changed the accepted answer. very uncool!!

Comment: Sorry if there is misunderstanding, I changed vote from my post to your post today and marked it as accepted answer because you helped me and it was your idea that made app working. I am not sure why it didn't work the first time so i just now checked your post again.

Answer (score 1):

while working with Angular fire version 5.4.2 and Angular 8 project, I had to use below syntax.  Need to pass parameter as QueryFn -

**CategoryService.ts**

```
getCategories():AngularFireList<any[]>{
return this.afDatabase.list('/categories', ref=>ref.orderByChild('name'));
```

}

and while calling getCategories method inside component -

**Component.ts**

```
constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {
categoryService.getCategories().valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
  this.categories = items;
});
```

}

Hope! it will work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`this.db.list('/avatars/').valueChanges().subscribe(d => { this.avatarhall = d.reverse() });`

> I hope this will work