# Angular Firestore Sorting documents by timestamp value

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question which I'm hoping someone could answer as it's been two days I'm trying to sort it with absolutely no luck.

I have a collection of documents, so far so good..

Each of this documents has a field "preferred_time" that has a timestamp as a value.

Is it possible to sort the documents inside the collection using this value as reference?

I tried:

```
 return this.afs.collection('viewings', ref => 
    ref.orderBy('preferred_time')
    );
```

but it doesn't seem to work with timestamps field types.

Please help!!

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort your preferred_time on desc or asc. Read more here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

```
 return this.afs.collection('viewings', ref => 
ref.orderBy('preferred_time','desc'))
);
```

Comment: Hi Jedi Schmedi, I had tried that already and it doesn't change. And by the way the order is optional, and if not specified set to ascending by default. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#orderBy

Comment: So my guess is orderBy doesn't work with timestamps?!

Comment: How do you set that value? Can you show a tad more code about how you post to DB.

Comment: At the moment I'm not posting, I'm populating the db using the fb console, so the timestamp is generated by firebase and it looks like this: 

    April 24, 2018 at 8:30:00 PM UTC+2

Comment: while the full method in the component looks like this: 

`getPropertyViewings(): AngularFirestoreCollection<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('viewings', ref =>
      ref.where('property_id', '==', this.property.id)
        .orderBy('preferred_time', 'asc')
    );
  }`

Comment: I will check when I get home. In my project I added Date() as an own element in the entity and then sorted on that. That worked well. But was created directly in my client.

Comment: Hey man, don't bother. I've sorted it, and orderBy works as it should.

Basically I had four dates 23/04/2018, 24/04/2018, 31/04/2018 and the one that wasn't being ordered was 25/04...2001, hence was displaying as first. I feel so bad. Apologies

Comment: also, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60919857/6662938